# Prestashop: How to include a block in a module?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a module and I want to display the "blocknewproducts" inside of it. What is the best option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we lack some more info but i will share a way to do it in **Prestashop 1.6.x**:

### Your module :

Given you have a custom hook named **displayMyModule** in your module **install** method :

```
public function install() {
    if (!parent::install() || !$this->registerHook('displayMyModule')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, where you want to display the content of this hook is up to you. For example if it's on a category page, in **category.tpl** you add

```
{hook::exec('displayMyModule')}
```

### Block new Products

Now to display the blocknewproducts we will create an **override** of this core module and register the `displayMyModule` hook :

in **/override/modules/blocknewproducts/blocknewproducts.php** :

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class BlockNewProductsOverride extends BlockNewProducts
{

    public function install()
    {
        $success = (parent::install() 
            && $this->registerHook('displayMyModule'));

        return $success;
    }

    public function hookDisplayMyModule($params)
    {
        return $this->hookRightColumn($params);
    }
}
```

In `hookDisplayMyModule` we simply return the hookRightColumn method to not rewrite code.

*Don't forget to go into back-office/modules and reinitialize blocknewproducts module*

And that's about it... but keep in mind that you could also just **override** the blocknewproducts module to register hooks **that already exist** like shown above.

**TLDR:** Maybe you don't need a module if you just want to show block new products elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, myModule is not for this purpose, so I'll need it anyway... Thanks so much for your help @philDL Do you know if there is a way to get blocknewproducts by jQuery?